# Error authenticating using aws-sdk and vault gem

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, hashicorp-vault

I am using the [aws-sdk for ruby](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/) and [vault-ruby](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault-ruby) for a proof of concept script. Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'vault'
require 'pp'
require 'trollop'
require 'aws-sdk'

opts = Trollop::options do
  opt :verify_ssl, "verify ssl connection"
  opt :address, "Vault Address", :type => :string, :default => "http://localhost:8200"
  opt :username, "Username to authenticate against Vault", :type => :string
  opt :password, "Password to authenticate against Vault", :default => ENV['VAULT_PASSWORD'], :type => :string
end

Trollop::die :username, "please supply a username" if ! opts[:username]
Trollop::die :password, "please supply a password" if ! opts[:password]


# Configure vault
Vault.configure do |config|
  config.address = opts[:address]
  config.ssl_verify = opts[:verify_ssl]
end

Vault.auth.userpass(opts[:username], opts[:password])

aws = Vault.logical.read("aws/creds/readonly")

@client = Aws::EC2::Client.new(access_key_id: aws.data[:access_key].to_s, secret_access_key: aws.data[:secret_key].to_s, region: 'us-west-2')
pp @client.describe_instances
```

Pretty simple. It auths against vault with username password, retrieves a credential from the AWS secret backend and then tries to list instances.

However, when I run this, I get the following issue:

```
/Users/l/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.7.13/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/raise_response_errors.rb:15:in `call': AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials (Aws::EC2::Errors::AuthFailure)
    from /Users/l/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.7.13/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/idempotency_token.rb:18:in `call'
    from /Users/l/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.7.13/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/param_converter.rb:20:in `call'
    from /Users/l/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.7.13/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/response_paging.rb:26:in `call'
    from /Users/l/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.7.13/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/response_target.rb:21:in `call'
    from /Users/l/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.7.13/lib/seahorse/client/request.rb:70:in `send_request'
    from /Users/l/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.7.13/lib/seahorse/client/base.rb:207:in `block (2 levels) in define_operation_methods'
    from aws.rb:33:in `<main>'
```

This makes no sense. If I print the credentials it creates using:

```
puts aws.data[:access_key]
```

And then modify the connection to have the info harcoded:

```
@client = Aws::EC2::Client.new(access_key_id: "access_key", secret_access_key: "secret_key" ,region: 'us-west-2')
```

It works with no problem at all!

Why would this be happening?

Comment: can you add a puts call in your code to make sure they are set before initializing the EC2 client?

Comment: They definitely are, I can see the generated keys in my debug output.